# Create an OEIS Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have quite a few problems on this site that deal with OEIS.  We have tons of problems asking you to produce the `nth` term (or the first `n` terms), and we even have a problem [specifically dealing with OEIS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49223/evolution-of-oeis)

I think that these problems are often quite interesting, and I could definitely see somebody searching/filtering by such problems.

However, I do see a disadvantage here.  Let's say a problem is shown to match a sequence on OEIS, but the OP doesn't update his question.  Do we:

1. Automatically tag the question?
2. If so, do we edit the question and add a link to the OEIS?
3. If not, how does the potential searcher find which OEIS sequence it matches?

So, please vote below on what you guys think we should do.

Answer (score 17):

## No, let's not create an OEIS tag

It would cause more problems than it would solve.

Comment: +1 Not because it would cause *problems*, but we already have a more encompassing [tag:sequence] tag, and I don't think we need to be more specific. (Although that tag wiki could use some love I guess)

Comment: @Geobits are you saying that any question that maps to an OEIS should be tagged with [tag:sequence]?  I don't really think my recent question http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/the-golf-cpu-golfing-challenge-sides-of-a-cuboid should be tagged [tag:sequence], but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I don't think that particular one should be tagged [oeis], either. It either is or isn't a sequence. If it is, you could tag it [sequence], and if it isn't, you shouldn't tag it [oeis]. But it's hard to argue that it should be tagged with a semi-related website's name dealing entirely with sequences, but not sequence itself.

Comment: The 'S' stands for "Sequences", so I agree with Geobits.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, let's create an OEIS tag

I think the tag would be useful.

Comment: -1, I don't think an OEIS tag would add any meaningful context to a challenge.