# Is [oeis] a synonym of [sequence]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Yesterday the [oeis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oeis) tag was created for [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105651/smallest-prime-with-a-twist-a068103) about an oeis sequence.  I assume that this tag would be used in the future for other oeis sequence questions (There was no usage guide or description until I added one simply linking to oeis.org).

Every question about an oeis sequence will most obviously also be tagged with the sequence sequence tag is it really worth having an [oeis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oeis) tag?

On the other hand this tag could be used to mark questions that are about *the oeis* rather than a specific sequence such as [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89376/automate-the-oeis).  However I could not find any other questions like that and it seems that, of the one question already tagged [oeis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oeis), it is not being used like that at current.

Comment: Yes: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5544/create-an-oeis-tag

Comment: My bad, didn't know about the meta discussion prior to posting.

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan Merrill mentioned, yes, we treat it as such. See [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5544/create-an-oeis-tag).

Technically though, if you're talking about tag synonyms, it is not an "official" tag synonym. I already edited the tags on the question you linked, and the tag must exist to be suggested as a tag synonym.